# Opening Foundation Reveal on Click & Callback Functions?

Tags: modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm migrating from jQueryTools Overlay, and I can't really grasp the docs on how to open a Reveal by JavaScript click event.

Supposedly I have this code:

```
<a href="#revealModal" class="revealTrigger">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<div id="revealModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
</div>
```

Usually, I code the click event in jQueryTools Overlay something like:

```
$('.revealTrigger').click(function() {
    $('#revealModal').reveal();
});
```

But this doesn't work. What's the equivalent correct code for it in Reveal?

And what about callback events? Can I write something like this:

```
$('.revealTrigger').click(function() {
    $('#revealModal').reveal({
        open: function(){
            // prepare some stuff before showing
        },
        opened: function(){
            // execute stuff prepared by open function
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Reveal modal can be opened in two ways, by attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
 <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
      <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
      <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
      <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

or by javascript:

```
<a class="large button" onclick="javascript:showModal();" href="#">Show Modal</a>

<script>
     $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', {
          opened: function () {
              alert('The couch was stolen!');
          },
          closed: function () {
              alert("Now it's yours again");
          }
     });
     $(document).foundation();
     function showModal() {
         $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');          
     }
</script>
```

Comment: How about callback events?

Comment: See my updated answer, someone just told me that to make the configuration work, it **important** that you do the settings first before the **foundation init** (`$(document).foundation();`)

Comment: It worked but I decided to use another plugin. It seems that it cannot do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the open, opened, close, and closed events.

```
#CoffeeScript
$("div[class$='-modal']").on "opened", ->
  console.log "howdy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
   $('#modal_id').bind('closed', function() {
     console.log("myModal closed!");
   });
```